# Do the Faceless Men take more than just a face?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Up until "Dragonstone" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E01) we have only seen faceless men change faces, but when Arya takes on the 'Face' of Walder Frey she assumes more than just his face. She takes on his voice, mannerisms, stature, and posture. Certainly, some of that can be mimicry (changing one's voice, etc), but when Arya (as Walder) stands to make a toast she is like him in more than just 'face', we get an especially good view of the hands and his height.

So, how* does the 'magic' of the House of Black & White/The Many Faced Gods work in respect to this? Does putting on the face of another grant one more than just a face?

*Note: other questions bring into question how or whether Arya still has access to that magic. For the purpose of this question let us assume that she does.*

*Edit: By "how" what I mean is 'to what extent' or 'how far does it go'. (not by what 'magically principal' (ie is it a transmutation or a glamour). The reference that points out that *memories* even come with it. The names "The Faceless Men" and "The Many-faced God" focus our attention on the 'facial' aspect but the 'magic' really appears to cover allow the 'wearer' access to the identity, in both mind and body.

Comment: IIRC, Jaqen becomes a black old man.

Comment: In the books, the faces also come with [memories](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/tv/0/game-thrones-faceless-men-does-aryas-face-changing-really-work/). The more you know.

Comment: Now, I want to see Arya-as-Frey making the introductory monolog entirely with Arya's voice !

Comment: Assume it's just magic, I don't think we'll get a detailed explanation of how exactly it works. You're reading into it too much, it's a fantasy show after all.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the faces are not just Mission-Impossible masks that are worn, but are a supernatural tool (no rot/stink, it somehow fits seamlessly, etc). Don't think any explanation of *how* that magic works is given, though.

Comment: @Ghoti and Chips if you transplant your comment to an answer, it directly responds to my intent.

Comment: @LeonX Great point, but I don't recall if we ever saw the black man's hands/feet... and since we don't know (unlike with Walder Frey) what he sounded like 'in real life' the voice *could* have just been a 'fake voice' Jaqen choose to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Face changing does not physically change the appearence of the wearer, it is an illusion. In actuality they have not changed their appearance they just appear that way to others. This is known due to the comparison of face changing to glamours with face changing being a form you cannot see through. Elaboration below but in short Arya is just a girl wearing a mask of a person.

What we know of faces is the following

In the books, which we can assume the mechanics are the same in the show, we see that faces have memories of the previous owners.

We can also relate this to warging as when a warg wargs an animal a piece of their selves is left inside and if another person wargs the same animal they can hear the voice of the original warg whispering to them.

Also to note there are 2 types of deception.

1. Glamours that can fool anyone that wants to be fooled but can be
   seen by those with enough knowledge or relation to the glamoured
   object. This is used by Melisandra in the show to hide her
   appearance
2. Are the faces which completely disguise the person as if they were
   the person whose face they are wearing. It is not known how
       this work it is just magic

So in summary

1. Faces contain memories that might actually be whispers from the
   original owner thus allowing replication of the mannerisms and
   behavior of the faces original owner
2. Face magic though unknown completely disguises the user as the owner of the face, height and all else included

Will update with sources shortly

Source for memories thanks to Ghoti and Chips
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/tv/0/game-thrones-faceless-men-does-aryas-face-changing-really-work/

Also wanted to add this personal theory
So warging works both ways when a warg wargs an animal the animal can influence the warg or if the warg is inexperienced enough the animal might even take over.

So if we consider that the face has some of the original owner in it and that face changing acts like warging then we may assume that the wearer allows the faces consciousness fragment into them allowing the Face to act as if it were the one alive and living but only being a part of consciousness allows the wearer to continue to maintain their own personality and exert their own prerogative. Still no idea how it changes them physically

Comment: OP is looking for how the magic allows Arya to assume Walder Frey's `height and hands`. While your answer gives us a bit of a peek into some of the workings of the magic, it doesn't exactly pertain to the question, yet.

Comment: @GhotiandChips The magic is never explained just trying to elaborate that it is different from a glamour making the owner impossible to discern as a fake

Comment: I didn't see evidence of OP being confused between glamours and Arya's Many-Faced God magic - not that it isn't interesting or relevant. My comment serves more as a reminder of what OP is looking for, which is essentially: How come Arya took on Walder's height and hands.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Never explained so updated first line to clarify that and try to fill in the details that we know

Comment: Walder Frey is around 30cm taller than Arya, so that's quite the jump in height. I've seen [Floyd Mayweather achieve a similar feat](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DEtxWs6WsAE4rmE.jpg), it's not difficult to imagine Arya preparing in a similar way, considering she was going through the trouble of using his wardrobe, too.

Comment: @GhotiandChips That's great, but it was more than the height hands and everything else that unless Arya has access to an SFX artist she'd be out of luck without unexplainable magic. Not to mention the voice

Comment: No, I wasn't claiming lack of magic. I brought up memories up at the top, anyway, which alludes to magic.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - So you're saying "Money" Mayweather serves the Many-Faced God?